# is there a way to fetch data from Jenkins builds using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jenkins

I tried to follow the documentation on Jenkins and Python and it was not much help.
https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

We have a jenkins link like this one:
https://myWebsite.com/job/BuildA/job/BuildA1/job/BuildA11/job/BuildA111/

if I need to fetch json data from BuildA111 using python, how do I do that?

I tried

```
user_name = 'myname'
password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
url = 'https://myWebsite.com/'

server = jenkins.Jenkins(url, username=user_name, password= password)
user = server.get_whoami()
version = server.get_version()
print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))

myJob = server.get_job_info('ECG', depth=0, fetch_all_builds=True)
print(myJob)
```

I get

```
# Hello Last Name, First Name from Jenkins x.xxx.x
#{'_class': 'com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder',
#  'name': 'launch',
#  'url': 'https://myWebsite.com/job/BuildA/job/BuildA1/'}
```

But I was not sure how to access /BuildA11 or /BuildA111 or even have a way to fetch any data from the json file in that build which has a link: https://myWebsite.com/job/BuildA/job/BuildA1/job/BuildA11/job/BuildA111/my_file.json

My project aims to iterate over all of those Builds and get the json info and store them. I first need help figuring out how to access data from BuildA111 and think I will be able to figure out the rest..

Comment: What is stopping you from fetching the JSON info for your job using the rest API?

Comment: @SiddharthKaul - thanks for the note. I was able to fetch data from this link: 'https://myWebsite.com/job/BuildA/job/BuildA1/job/BuildA11/job/BuildA111/my_file.json'... the other part which I need help with is how to iterate over the jobs I have on jenkins.